# how to secure Socket communication so that only authorised client application can connect or listen to the port of server application

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have server application which runs on local host and the client also runs on local host.
As of now I am using java.net.serversocket and any application which has the ip and port detail of server can listen to the port. 
My requirement is to secure the ports or secure the communication between the server and client application such that only my application client (authorised) one can listen to the ports or connect to server application. The data sent to and from client and server also has to be secured.

Apologies if naming conventions are not correct. I have been searching for solution and couldn't get anything for this, all I got is how to connect and make application communicate using socket programming , but no where I got the answer as how to secure the communication.

Comment: Whoever has down voted the question can please explain the reason to do so? give me input on how i can improve the question to be more specific or if more details required?  Only down voting without inputs just shows arrogance and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

What you need here is some sort of authentication method to authorise only your client to communicate with the server. If you are using an existing communication protocol then it might have a specification for authentication already. If you are using your own protocol then you'll have come up with your own design for authentication.

It could be as simple as the server [issuing some sort of request for authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication) to the client. The client would then have to provide a satisfactory response (eg a user/password) otherwise the server would close the connection.

I would recommend taking a look at how some other protocols (eg [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)) handle authentication to get some insight and also understand potential pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what i actually need is that the client will not be able to connect to server Socket if not authorized. for example my client app and server app both running in local host. If some other app or through terminal is listing to the ports can see the request response or make request to the server socket. what i need is only my client app should be able to make request to serverSocket. Please let me know if this can be done. or correct me if something wrong i am saying.